# Ubuntu 18 What is my Desktop and how to get Xorg

Tags: desktop-environments, remote, xrdp

I am now realizing that when remoting through xRDP I must choose the right Desktop. How can I check to see what desktop is installed?

Thanks

Comment: You could try `echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP`.

Comment: Ask the person who installed it, check apt logs to see what was installed (if a full desktop was installed it's very easy, but if only parts were installed you should still see it), however if you installed Ubuntu Core 18 by default it has no desktop as its an appliance release and expected to be used headless (likewise Ubuntu 18.04 server)

Comment: I installed it myself.

Answer (score 0):

**1. To get available session managers, go with:**

```
sudo update-alternatives  --display x-session-manager
```

**2.To get available window managers, go with :**

```
sudo update-alternatives  --display x-window-manager
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between session manager and window manager?

Comment: In a nutshell, window manager is the basic building block of graphical display (essentially allows to control and open windows graphically), and a desktop manager builds upon a window manager (a graphical desktop environment will always include  a window manager) but also allows for all additional features like panels, application/start bar, widgets etc.